# Как запустить сервер Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Надо запустить сервер не локально, то есть, чтобы сервер работал на другом устройстве в другой сети. Можете пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com)**

`ngrok http -host-header=localhost:8080 80`

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, как открыть с его помощью мой сайт на Vue